# AxiosError when integrating Stripe with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, stripe-payments

I am relatively new to Next.js, and I though I have been encountering some bugs and issues here and there, I have been able to overcome most of them. The latest one I have not been able to figure out, so let's see if somebody else knows what's going on.

I am creating an e-commerce platform on Next.js, Redux and Axios. For the moment I am using fake data to populate the products. When creating a checkout session, the data of the items in the cart is pushed (I can console.log() and I see the items in the terminal. However, the mapping of the checkout session to Stripe is not working. The error I get is an AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdtHD.png)

I am trying to add the item data dynamically to the checkout session as follows:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { items, email } = req.body;
  const transformedItems = items.map((item) => ({
    description: item.description,

    // if quantities are bundled, this needs to change.

    quantity: 1,

    price_data: {
      currency: 'usd',

      unit_amount: item.price * 100,

      product_data: {
        name: item.title,

        images: [item.image],
      },
    },
  }));

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: transformedItems,

    mode: 'payment',

    success_url: `${process.env.HOST}/success`,

    cancel_url: `${process.env.HOST}/checkout`,

    metadata: {
      email,

      images: JSON.stringify(items.map((item) => item.image)),
    },
  });

  res.status(200).json({ id: session.id });
};
```

I have also tried copying the exact code from the Stripe documentation and implementing the changes, but this hasn't changed anything either.
I know, Stripe has made some changes to their API, and that for instance you can't specify anymore with statements like
`payment_method_types: ["card"],`
anymore. So I took it out.

I have not included any code from the checkout piece, as this seems to be working (as stated, it console.logs() just fine. I can provide this as well though, if someone thinks the issue might be there.

Thanks in advance.
Nela.

Comment: A status code 500 means there is an error on the backend. If the server is under your control, then you need to look at the server logs to see what the problem is. The server logs will have a stack trace that shows you where the problem occurs. If you need help understanding the stacktrace, you will need to include it in your question.

Comment: Is this a server-side or client-side AJAX request? If it's the latter, check your network tab to see the full output of your failed request (marked in red in Chrome Devtools). You should be able to get more information about the failed request there. If it's failing on the Stripe side, the Response Headers and Body should have more information there to help you debug. If it's failing on your own `success` and `checkout` callbacks, your server logs might have additional information that can help you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, @maiorano84!
Thanks for your swift answers! I have checked my console, and the error that was given was from Stripe. It read as follows:

StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or `line_items.images` in this API version. Please use `line_items.price` or `line_items.price_data`.

So I moved the item.description I had outside of the product_data object, into it. And it worked. Thank you for your responsiveness, it really helped me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice) and [maiorano84](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347308/maiorano84) whose hints in the comments:

> A status code 500 means there is an error on the backend. If the server is under your control, then you need to look at the server logs to see what the problem is. The server logs will have a stack trace that shows you where the problem occurs. If you need help understanding the stacktrace, you will need to include it in your question. – [Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice) [22 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74435395/axioserror-when-integrating-stripe-with-next-js/74436008#comment131401572_74435395)

> Is this a server-side or client-side AJAX request? If it's the latter, check your network tab to see the full output of your failed request (marked in red in Chrome Devtools). You should be able to get more information about the failed request there. If it's failing on the Stripe side, the Response Headers and Body should have more information there to help you debug. If it's failing on your own success and checkout callbacks, your server logs might have additional information that can help you. – [maiorano84](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347308/maiorano84) [22 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74435395/axioserror-when-integrating-stripe-with-next-js/74436008#comment131401672_74435395)

led me to the answer. I checked my console, and the error that was given was from Stripe. It read as follows:

> StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot use line_items.amount, line_items.currency, line_items.name, line_items.description, or line_items.images in this API version. Please use line_items.price or line_items.price_data.

So I moved the `item.description` I had outside of the `product_data` object, into it, and it worked.
The code looks now like this:

```
    const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { items, email } = req.body;
  const transformedItems = items.map((item) => ({

    // if quantities are bundled, this needs to change.
    quantity: 1,

    price_data: {
      currency: 'usd',

      unit_amount: item.price * 100,

      product_data: {
        name: item.title,
        description: item.description,
        images: [item.image],
      },
    },
  }));

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: transformedItems,

    mode: 'payment',

    success_url: `${process.env.HOST}/success`,

    cancel_url: `${process.env.HOST}/checkout`,

    metadata: {
      email,

      images: JSON.stringify(items.map((item) => item.image)),
    },
  });

  res.status(200).json({ id: session.id });
};
```

Comment: This area is for answers only. Please edit your question if you want to add the error details. Then [edit] this answer to show the change to your code that you describe in the last sentence.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - how about this? I've edited the answer, quoting your comment and the other comment with attribution, and made it clear what the OP did.

Comment: @WaiHaLee That looks really good. Also, some code would improve the question. But I think the OP will have to add that.